# what is the default sorting column in log analytics workspace with KQL queries?

Tags: azure, kql, azure-log-analytics, azure-log-analytics-workspace

I am querying **Azure Log Analytics Workspace** with KQL. I wonder by which column the rows in a table are ordered(sorted)? I am assuming that we don't use order. Is it sorted randomly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If table is maintaining datetime field (Ingestion Datetime Field mainly), generally by default its sorted-on date. But there is not as such ordering/sorting for time if considered and it is totally random.

[image]

If you want to order or sort it you can use :
**order by** and **dsc** , **asc** in you kql query.

or you can use arrows to sort it:
[image]